# What exactly is persistence?

Tags: persistence, persistent, persistent-storage

I've searched all over the web for definitions, but I'm still confused. I've narrowed it all down to two different defintions:
 *"A data structure is persistent if it support saccess to multiple version*" and "*Persistence is the ability of an object to survive the lifetime of the OS process in which it resides*".

To me, these mean different things, but maybe I'm just not getting it. Could someone please explaing to me in a basic way what exactly persistence means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This word means different things in different contexts:

Persistent data structures create new copies of themselves to incorporate changes (all versions are accessible AND modifiable at any time).

Persistence in your second example refers to the ability of objects to be stored in non-volatile memory, such as a hard disk. Otherwise, they would be destroyed when the OS ends its session.

Comment: Thank. Could you explain how, if at all, these two different contexts relate to one another. I'm learning about Hibernate, and I read both defintions for the persistence that it helps to provide, so I'm still a little confused.